# Unpack a given number of items in Python?

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

Is there any way to use the 'splat' operator (e.g. `a, *rest = somelist`) in such a way that it consumes a certain number of items?

Use case: I want to split some input I'm getting into a number, a list of lists, another number, and another list of lists.

My input looks like this:

```
5
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
5
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

And I want the names `first_num`, `first_arrangement`, `second_num`, `second_arrangement` such that:

```
first_num == 5
first_arrangement == [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], ...]
```

and so on.

To do this, it'd be useful to be able to consume a set number of items from the iterable I've got yielding the lines. Something like this would be ideal as an intermediate step:

`first_num, *[4]first_arrangement, second_num, *[4]second_arrangement = lines`

What's the normal/canonical/Pythonic way of solving this?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: can't you simply slice your arguments => `first_arrangement = args[1:5]` ...?

Comment: In answer to the first question, there is no way of doing this with `*`

Comment: Python 3 - and yes, I just wondered if there was something a bit neater, comparable to the splat operator.

Comment: Hmm alright, thanks @MJeffryes, I'll stick around to see what people come up with as a solution for the use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the canonical, pythonic way to do this would be to put the onus on the generator that you're iterating over. I'd define a generator function like so:

```
import itertools

def generate_arrangements(iterable, size=4):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        yield next(iterator)
        yield list(list(row) for row in itertools.islice(iterator, size))
```

Say you have your data in a list like so:

```
data = [
    5,
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16],
    5,
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
]
```

Then writing:

```
first_num, first_arr, second_num, second_arr = generate_arrangements(data)
```

gives you your desired output:

```
>>> first_num
5
>>> first_arr
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

You can also yield the number and arrangement at the same time, and have the user do some extra unpacking, which might be a more natural approach:

```
import itertools

def generate_arrangements(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        number =  next(iterator)
        arrangement = list(list(row) for row in itertools.islice(iterator, 4))
        yield number, arrangement

(first_num, first_arr), (second_num, second_arr) = generate_arrangements(data)
```

As @JoranBeasley writes in the comments, this form makes it easy to use tuple unpacking in a for-loop, like this:

```
for num,arr in generate_arrangements(data):
    print(num) 
    print(arr)
```

Comment: great answer ... I would add `for num,arr in generate_arangements(data)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks! Good suggestion, I've tacked it on to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what format you are receiving the data. Are these strings, data in file, etc. Assume `data` is a StringIO object of the your sample input. 
You can use `itertools.islice` on an iterator to extract n items, e.g:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> d = iter(data)
>>> first_num = int(next(d))
>>> first_arrangement = [[int(x) for x in l.split()] for l in islice(d, 4)]
>>> print(first_num, first_arrangement)
5  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```